# Creating space between an element and its border

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to create a spacing between an element and its outermost border. (EDIT: he wants to do two borders between the element proper and the outside of the box-model box. This gives him the room of using the margin, border *and* padding to achieve his goal). So far my searches in Google and here produced no solution to this.

I am trying to avoid using images to acheive this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the multiple css technique ([here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/)), and using `border-color: transparent` to create a transparent spacing between the element and its border.

Answer (score 10):

You want padding.

Here's a link to a site that demonstrates "margin", "border", and "padding" for an element. http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

However, there used to be a problem with IE's rendering of the box model and the "rest of the world" in that IE used a different mechanism to determine "overall width". You need to understand that if you plan on supporting IE7 (two generations old) or older.

I imagine that using the "rest of the world" way will be sufficient for your needs.

For the rest of the world (and the sake of when that link no longer works) here's an ascii version of the same diagram:

```
+----------------------------+
|                            |
|          margin            |
|                            |
|   *******border**********  |
|   *                     *  |
|   *      padding        *  |
|   *                     *  |
|   *   ---------------   *  |
|   *   ---------------   *  |
|   *   ---ELEMENT-----   *  |
|   *   ---------------   *  |
|   *   ---------------   *  |
|   *                     *  |
|   ***********************  |
|                            |
|                            |
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: the padding doesnt seem to work..., using the following css there is no transperent spacing between the black color and the red border: `div {background-color: black; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 5px solid red; padding: 20px}`

Comment: @GZaidman Then you need to nest a div inside a div. I thought you wanted spacing from the element. Background-color does not affect only the element. You were not clear on that when you first posted the question, and then I was afk. Hope this helps.

Comment: I read about multiple borders ([here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/)), and I think it might help solve the problem without using another div, but I dont know if it's possible to create a transparent border

Comment: There is no such CSS property as "multiple borders". What that article discusses is advanced CSS concepts. If you notice, it's effectively creating a wrapper element (using :before) that can do what you want. I suggest sticking to the simpler to manipulate concepts until you've built up more familiarity with more complex examples like pseudo selectors. For what it's worth, it was about five years after I first heard about :before and :after and it was still another six months or so before I really got how they worked. (I didn't have a need for them either)

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this with inset border

```css
.box {
    background-color: #e1309e;
    border: 10px solid #6a51d2;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #f3f5f6 inset;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SteeleRocky/pmnfe5jw/11/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of 2 things. What you're coding for will determine what you use.

Padding could be added to the **container (outer)** element to push the element inside away from it's border.

Margin could be used on the **inner**  element to push itself away from the container.

My experience is that if you're designing for the web, use either, checking in all browsers to make sure that your spacing is correct.

However, if you're coding for an HTML email, you should use Margin - in some applications (Outlook 2007) Padding does not work in some instances.

Answer (score 0):

The backgroud-clip can be used:

```
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  padding: 5px;
  background: green;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: I found "background-clip: content-box;" to work for my situation 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip